# Read text between two delimiters uisng Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file with below text:

```
REPLACE VIEW xyz_REPORTS.D_ACCT AS LOCK ROW FOR ACCESS SELECT
CT_ACTIV_CD, CCT_STAT_CD, UM_ACCT_IN, NTRN_ACCT_IN, EW_HSHLD_IN,
NTR_HSHLD_IN, CASE WHEN RETL_ACCT_IN = 'N' THEN 'X'
     ELSE NTR_HSHLD_IN END AS NTR_HSHLD_CD, W_CREAT_TS, W_LOAD_TS FROM  I_DATA.D_ACCT_FIN ;
```

I want to read the contents of this text that is between "Replace" and ";". I want to use regular expressions in Python. This file contains other text as well apart from this.

Answer (score -2):

So you can use [regular expression](http://www.pythonlearn.com/html-007/cfbook012.html) library of python. Here is the snippet for your query:

```
import re
f=open('file')
for i in f:
    st=i
txt=re.findall('REPLACE(.*?);',st)
print " ".join(txt)
```

Output:
 VIEW xyz_REPORTS.D_ACCT AS LOCK ROW FOR ACCESS SELECT CT_ACTIV_CD, CCT_STAT_CD, UM_ACCT_IN, NTRN_ACCT_IN, EW_HSHLD_IN, NTR_HSHLD_IN, CASE WHEN RETL_ACCT_IN = 'N' THEN 'X' ELSE NTR_HSHLD_IN END AS NTR_HSHLD_CD, W_CREAT_TS, W_LOAD_TS FROM I_DATA.D_ACCT_FIN